# URL rewrite and RewriteBase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite an URL from `mysite.com/home/my-article` to `mysite.com/my-article`.

When I try to change the name of the "home" folder the whole site goes down so I guess this is what it has to be named.

I'm working with the file based CMS KirbyCMS. I have tried to set the `RewriteBase` to `/home` but that gives me a internal server error.

Is there anything I could do in the `.htaccess` file with `RewriteBase`, or do I need to look other places? If yes how could I do this?

```
# Kirby .htaccess

# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# enable awesome urls. i.e.:
# http://yourdomain.com/about-us/team
RewriteEngine on

# make sure to set the RewriteBase correctly
# if you are running the site in a subfolder.
# Otherwise links or the entire site will break.
#
# If your homepage is http://yourdomain.com/mysite
# Set the RewriteBase to:
#
RewriteBase /home

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the kirby folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# Additional recommended values
# Remove comments for those you want to use.
#
# AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#
# php_flag short_open_tag on
```

Thanks!

Comment: include your `.htaccess` content

Comment: @roullie here you go

Comment: Is your htaccess inside /home folder?

Comment: Use only relevant tags, please. URL rewriting has nothing to do with PHP or any CMS. On the other hand, web server you're using is very important information.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy sorry, I just dont know how to fix this and what is and what is not relevant here really.